# How to alert the value as a string if we have an item with a class as a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
var token = "myClass";
$('a.' + token);
```

And I would like to do this:

```
alert($('a.' + token));
```

But i get:

```
[object Object]
```

While I would like to have as an alert

```
a.myClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(..) will get the element from the DOM. Since alert() can only alert strings, you get [object Object]. Remove $(..) and you will get the string you want.

Answer (score 2):

`$('a.' + token)` : It's really an object.

If you want to alert it's class then use:

```
alert(a.attr('class'));
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"

Comment: sorry, I was missing a quote in class

Comment: Typo, should be `alert(a.attr("class"));` and using jQuery 1.6+ it should be `alert(a.attr("prop"));`

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
$('a.' + token);
```

You are returned a [jQuery Object type](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).  The documentation does not show how to return the selector that was used to find an object.  Most likely, the jQuery object will never return the selector because of the complexities involved with all the methods that could have been used to select the object.

Under no circumstances will:

```
alert($('a.' + token));
```

return

```
a.myClass
```

More likely you are looking for

```
var mySelector = 'a.' + token;
var $object = $(mySelector);
alert(mySelector);
```